# Does jQuery deferred re-order JSON it converts to objects? How can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-deferred

Does the jQuery deferred object re-order the JSON it gets from PHP? In my Network console, I can see the JSON coming back in the expected order. However when I do this:

```
function myFn(){

   //return some $.ajax({ ... });

}

myFn().done(function(returned_data){

   moreFn(returned_data);

});


function moreFn(returned_data){

  console.log(returned_data);

}
```

The order is substantially changed. How can I prevent this.

Comment: JSON objects do not have an order in their keys. Use an array instead.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean? How is the JSON in the network console different from the `returned_data` that you log (apart from one being a string and the other an object)?

Comment: @Bergi Of course. I didn't write the backend code and wasn't even thinking about that. Thanks.